# Hitting strange error: "DOMException 105" in IOS app. Looking for guidance on how to locate the bug in my code

Tags: ios, iphone

Having trouble finding any reference to this error - anywhere!

It happens at the same point every time - just as I click on a UITableView row element.  Below is the stack trace - can someone provide any suggestions as to what the problem might be and/or how to go about finding the bug?

Thank you!

---

```
    2016-11-04 10:12:56.096 Golf W[51137:9704786] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'DOMException', reason: '*** DOMException 105'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d51b34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cf7c21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d51b299 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   WebCore                             0x0000000111f50072 _ZN7WebCore17raiseDOMExceptionEi + 370
    4   WebCore                             0x0000000111f5008e _ZN7WebCore23raiseTypeErrorExceptionEv + 14
    5   WebCore                             0x0000000111ed842e -[DOMRange setStart:offset:] + 158
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010a319143 -[UIWebDocumentView text] + 292
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010a09a56a _UIViewDescriptionAppendTextIfApplicable + 96
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010a09a71d -[UIView(UIDebugging) description] + 147
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4f0d4a -[NSArray descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 362
    10  Foundation                          0x00000001096ce3be _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 66
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d459407 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 10983
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4568f7 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 263
    13  AccessibilityUtilities              0x000000011e001cd7 _AXStringForArgs + 333
    14  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0b908 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilitySubviewsForGettingElementsWithOptions:] + 199
    15  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0c761 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 743
    16  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0c7ec -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 882
    17  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0c7ec -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 882
    18  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0c7ec -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 882
    19  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0c7ec -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 882
    20  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0c7ec -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 882
    21  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0c7ec -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 882
    22  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0c7ec -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 882
    23  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0c7ec -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 882
    24  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0c7ec -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 882
    25  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0ccef +[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilityElementsAndContainersDescendingFromViews:options:sorted:] + 472
    26  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0d0ed -[UIApplication(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilityViewChildrenWithOptions:referenceWindow:] + 128
    27  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea0b13e -[NSObject(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilityEnumerateSiblingsWithParent:options:usingBlock:] + 896
    28  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea093d4 -[NSObject(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilityElementsInDirectionWithCount:options:] + 723
    29  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea16903 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:forParameter:] + 1360
    30  UIAccessibility                     0x000000011ea024ae _copyParameterizedAttributeValueCallback + 211
    31  AXRuntime                           0x000000011e140cbc _AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 216
    32  AXRuntime                           0x000000011e13b6a5 _XCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 447
    33  AXRuntime                           0x000000011e14a545 mshMIGPerform + 266
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4acf89 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4acf01 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 465
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4a5045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d4a4494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110352a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    39  UIKit                               0x0000000109fd3f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    40  Golf W                           0x00000001087f766f main + 111
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e71168d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do when a table row is selected? It would be very helpful if we could see some code.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew, I'll pull some together and update the post.

Comment: I'm seeing here a webkit related crash. More information is needed here.

Comment: Update.  the code behind my UITableView is 3 versions old and has not been changed in that time.  I have just seen this bug since my recent update to Xcode 8 when I also noticed that ALL of my HTMLview widgets got completely wrecked in my storyboard.  To fix those, I used the "Reset to suggested constraints" in the GUI editor.  So I went into this UITableView and did the same "constraints reset" and am now unable to reproduce the condition.  Is it plausible, based on the stack trace, that this had to do with UI constraints in the storyboard?

Comment: I wouldn't expect IB changes to be the root cause of a runtime crash. I'm seeing this exact same issue but I never had any problems with the constraints I set up. That said, a major issue is that right now I'm targeting iOS >= 9 and using a UIWebView instead of WKWebview.

Comment: This problem, is rising when voiceover is on.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue was searching for solution since last 2 days. At last today I found solution either you need to add `self.view.isAccessibilityElement = true` in `viewDidLoad` or set Attribute property of view in interface as below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when VoiceOver was on while loading a webview. It seemed like it was referencing the content in the webview before it was fully loaded. To stop this crash from happening, I simply hid the accessibility elements until after the webview was loaded. Be sure to set the ViewController as the `UIWebViewDelegate`. Then:

ObjC example:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [self.view setAccessibilityElementsHidden:YES];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
   [self.view setAccessibilityElementsHidden:NO];
}
```

Swift example:
(You should be using WKWebView so I'll give you an example of that below). Be sure to set the ViewController as `WKNavigationDelegate`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   view.accessibilityElementsHidden = true
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
   view.accessibilityElementsHidden = false
}
```

Hope it helps.